# Activate Month dropdown only when Year is selected from dropdown in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Please let me know how to achieve this scenario.

I am using jquery datepicker. now my requirement is that User should only be able to select Year first than Month and than day. this is for Date of birth capturing. Please help me in this.

```
$(".datePicker", $context).each( function() {
                var baseOptions = {
                    inline: true,
                    dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showMonthAfterYear: true,
                    buttonText: "Select date"
                };

                var attr = $(this).attr("min");
                if (attr != undefined) {
                    baseOptions.minDate = attr;
                    baseOptions.yearRange = "+0:+5";
                }

                attr = $(this).attr("max");
                if (attr != undefined) {
                    baseOptions.maxDate = attr;
                    baseOptions.yearRange = "-120:+0";
                }

                attr = $(this).attr("setBirthdate");
                if(attr!=undefined){

                    var date = new Date(attr);
                    date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear()-12)
                    baseOptions.defaultDate = date;
                }
                    options = {
                        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){

                            $(this).val(dateText).trigger('change');
                            $(inst).hide();
                        }
                    };
                    $(this).datepicker($.extend(baseOptions, options));
                    $(this).on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }).datepicker($.extend(baseOptions, options));
                //}
            }
```

Comment: Please provide more code, and try formatting it.

Comment: @Mark Provided the complete datepicker code I am using.

Comment: Im confused, the whole point of a datepicker is to make picking a date easier. why would you want to complicate that  by forcing the user to select the date in a specific order?

Comment: That is becoz users while selecting their DOB are not selecting year of birth which is than taken as default and thus loss of business and revenue

Comment: Fair enough, if that's been an issue for you, the answer below should do the trick : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, I dont think there is really a need for this. However, if you really need this to work this way, I'd use something like [combobox](http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/) and add a little css/jQuery to get this effect

```js
$(function(){
    $('#date').combodate();  
    
    $('.year').change(function(){
        $(this).parent('.combodate').find('.month').show();
    });
    
    $('.month').change(function(){
        $(this).parent('.combodate').find('.day').show();
    });
    
});
```

```css
.day{
    display:none;
}
.month{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/prettify/prettify-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/combodate.js"></script>
<script src="http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/momentjs/moment.min.2.5.0.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="date" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY" name="date" value="">
```